# Is it possible to detect another application from the current app in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to create sticky button which is on screen like hike button in ios

[image]

If i detect that application(WhatsApp) state event so i solve this problem. Thats why i need to create another application launched event.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do this on iOS, Apps are sandboxed and can't interact with the system in the way you would like. Also you can't add a button on the screen if your app is not in the foreground.

Comment: it means we can't add sticky like hike in other application.while our app is in background.

Comment: Yes that means that you can't add sticky button like hike on iOS.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps on iOS are sandboxed and can not directly communicate with other apps directly. There are some API's in the iOS SDK which allows some interaction, mostly audio, share of items.

Apple does not expose to you app if an other app is launched, so checking that an other is launched is not possible.

The second issue is that you can draw on de screen outside of you own apps windows. So you will not be able to draw a button on top of some other app.

Comment: Ok i got it. Thank you.